# Worklight 6.1.0.1 - Servlets 3.0 - Can't Deploy to WAS 7

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server

We recently have applied an update to Worklight 6.1.0.1. For our surprise, after a build we generated, the web deployment descriptor has generated a Servlet 3.0 spec reference, so now we can't deploy this into WAS 7 anymore.

Does anyone can confirm this has been changed into this version and what could be a workaround? Is there some configuration on ant tasks so we can control we need 2.5?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this shouldn't have changed. In Worklight 6.1 (and 6.1.0.1) the servlet schema version in the web.xml should be 2.4. There was an issue in Worklight 6.0.0.0 and 6.0.0.1 where the schema version was set to 3.0. But once that issue was identified it was fixed via [APAR PI05761](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI05761) in Worklight 6.0.0.2. So, in Worklight versions 6.0.0.2 and later and 6.1.0.0 and later, the servlet schema version should be set to 2.4.

I just created a new project using the 6.1.0.1 studio and my web.xml has this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```